# AndroidManifest.xml cannot resolve android:label="@string/app_name"

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have tried invalidating/restarting caches and inserting ACTION-VIEW intent filters but cannot get this issue resolved. Is there something wring with my code? I've noted the sticking points below as HERE. Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.camp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"         <---- HERE
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">                           <---- HERE
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.view" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.SERVER_URL"
            android:value="@string/back4app_server_url" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/gBd2UqK3ATKzctBRlDQJUDrshmXX2gvxcRzmz7vj" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="@string/rotdD7vWfLUhUwlaGfEvFctl8KYFIENjb2lOYgh2" />
        android:name=".App"
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Goto `res\values\strings.xml` and add:

```
<string name="app_name">AppName</string>
```